# How can I run an intractive console command from the controller in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, console, command

I'm writing a code making entity in symfony controller, and want to run the make:entity console command which asks question for fields. How can I answer console command questions automatically in controller?

By now the output is :

Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields! Success! Next: When you're ready, create a migration with make:migration

```
public function makeEntity(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);
    $input = new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'make:entity',
        'name' => 'Payment',
    ]);
    $input->setInteractive(true);
    $question =new QuestionHelper();
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);
    $content = $output->fetch();
    return new Response($content);
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this myself but the input stream of the process component might do it.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#streaming-to-the-standard-input-of-a-process